# Can't resolve radium

Tags: reactjs, radium

I am new to [React](https://reactjs.org) Environment, and was going through a tutorial and tried to install [Radium](https://formidable.com/open-source/radium/) for css pseudo behaviour using visual integrated terminal.

```
npm i --save radium
```

the radium has been installed and added to the package.json

[image]

but after making changes and saving compilation has been failed and throwing the following error.

> Module not found: Can't resolve './../../webpack/buildin/global.js' in 'D:\maximillian-react\react-complete-guide\node_modules\radium\es'

What went wrong?

and Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, It's really bad but I found what went wrong, I just installed the dependencies using

```
npm install
```

and everything is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
npm install --save radium --force
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Answer (score 0):

After installing Radium stop your React development server `ctrl+c` and then run:

```
yarn start
```

or

```
npm start
```

If necessary, before restarting development server run:

```
npm install
```

as well and that will fix any missing dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

check the syntax for your import for importing radium in respective components the correct syntax I have attached in the code snippets . please do check

```
import Radium from 'radium'
```